# JSON Array filter by inner property

Tags: javascript, json, filter

I have a JSON that has the following structure. How can I filter the objects in it based on lets say NETWORK type?

```
[
       {
          "101":{
             "LAT":"43.348",
             "LONG":"25.082",
             "NETWORK":"QR",
          },
          "102":{
             "LAT":"43.348",
             "LONG":"25.082",
             "NETWORK":"PR",
          },
          "104":{
             "LAT":"43.348",
             "LONG":"25.082",
             "NETWORK":"QR",
          }
       }
]
```

Comment: Are you aware that this is an array with only one element? How do you want to filter this array? Do you want to filter the object? First you should parse this data with `JSON.parse`.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this (ES6):

```js
var data = [
       {
          "101":{
             "LAT":"43.348",
             "LONG":"25.082",
             "NETWORK":"QR",
          },
          "102":{
             "LAT":"43.348",
             "LONG":"25.082",
             "NETWORK":"PR",
          },
          "104":{
             "LAT":"43.348",
             "LONG":"25.082",
             "NETWORK":"QR",
          }
       }
];

function filterdata(findkey, findvalue) {
  var mydata = data; //any parsing here
  
  return Object.keys(mydata[0]).map(function(key){
    return { key: key, value: mydata[0][key]};
  }).filter(function(element){
     return element.value[findkey] === findvalue;
  }).reduce(function(result, element) {
     result[element.key] = element.value;
     return result;
  }, {})
};

console.log(filterdata("NETWORK", "QR"))
```

Basically, you convert the objects into an array, filter that and then convert the result back into an object.

Answer (score 0):

You could first parse the json and then filter like this:

```
const filtered = Object.values(JSON.parse(data)[0]).filter(
  it => it.NETWORK === 'QR'
)
```

Notice that I am using `data[0]` since your array only has a single item.